# Error "fix_county_string(s) NameError: name 's' is not defined." I am trying to fix all counties in the file

Tags: python, function

Consider:

```
def fix_county_string(s):
    """ Insert Docstring """
    fp = open("michigan_COVID_08_24_21.txt", "r")
    fp.readline()
    for line in fp:
        county = line[24:43]
        x = county.split()
        t = x.pop(-1)
        s = x.append("County")
        return s
fix_county_string(s)
```

The parameter is s, a string. Every county name ends with the places; if it correctly ends in places, do nothing (simply return s). Otherwise, correct the ending word to be place. Specifically, if not, fix it.

Comment: You never defined the `s` you are passing into the function on the line `fix_county_string(s)`

Comment: quite a few errors and misinterpretations here. prefer `with open` instead, and `append` doesn’t return anything.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim i cant just delete it. what i want is to return the string s back but it's not returning anything.

Comment: @YonesMussa I didn't say delete it... I said it's not defined. You are not passing anything into the function. Also, that's not how you return something.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim how would i go about fixing it

Comment: @YonesMussa Well you don't actually use the `s` you pass into the function. So change the function def to `def fix_county_string():` and where you call it change it to `my_results = fix_country_string()`. That will give you the results of the return statement in the variable `my_results`. But then you will start to see some of the other problems with this code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is a Q&A site, but this is not a question. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You can [edit].

Comment: Don't vandalize posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
def fix_county_string():
    """ Insert Docstring """
    fp = open("michigan_COVID_08_24_21.txt", "r")
    s = ''
    for line in fp:
        county = line[24:43]
        x = county.split()
        t = x.pop(-1)
        x.append("County")
        s += line + ' '.join(x)
    return s
s = fix_county_string()
```

I think this is what you are trying to do. You can write back the output in a file.